# Using AndroidInjector (Dagger 2.10) to inject a Service inside a library

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, androidinjector

According to [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html) we could use `AndroidInjector` to inject any Android component, in this case I'm looking to inject a Service using either `DaggerIntentService` or calling directly `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` in my service. I understand that we need to setUp a subComponent for the service like:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = ...)
public interface MyServiceSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<MyService> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  public abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyService> {}
}
```

The question is that in all the examples in order to be able to user the AndroidInject, we need to build the main component in the application and then Dagger does the rest. My problem is that since my `Service` is inside a library project I do not have an `Application` class to add the final wiring needed by these components. This can be achieved using normal Dagger2 setUp adding an `inject(MyService service)` to my library component and the wiring directly on my onCreate but I would like to use the new components, is this possible?